# Azure Function Key Vault Attribute Binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

Can you use key vault secrets instead of `appsettings.json` on attribute bindings e.g.

```
[FunctionName("QueueMessageHandler")]
public static void Run(
     [QueueTrigger(queueName: "%queueName%", Connection = "%connection%")]string myQueueItem)
{
 *** function code here ***
}
```

so my variables `%queueName%` and `%connection%` would be read from KeyVault rather than appsettings

Is this possible and how would you do it.

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't for Triggers, but you can for Bindings. Check out the Imperative Bindings (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#imperative-bindings) if you want to know more about them.

Comment: hi, looks that way, bit of a halfway house solution :-)

Comment: It's not supported today. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/746 which tracks this.